# Socket programming in R to receive UDP stream

Tags: r

In Python I am able to write a code for socket programming to receive a Data stream via UDP.

However, how can I have an equivalent code in R to do the same?

```
import socket, traceback   
host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

counter = 1500
while counter > 0:
    counter -= 1
    try:
    message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
    message = message.decode() 
    data = message.split(",")
    print(data)


except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

In R I tried with below code, which is not successful. I do realize I need to somewhere mention that its is UDP and all, but unable to find those settings.

I need to receive the 'Stream' of Data from a Device. 
Do I need to have R-server for this?

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
os             linux-gnu
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
RStudio        Version 1.0.44

```
server <- function(){
  while(TRUE){
    writeLines("Listening...")
    con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 5555, blocking=TRUE,server=TRUE, open="r+")
    data <- readLines(con, 1)
    print(data)
    close(con)
 }
}

server()
```

Comment: Not directly related, but in python, a `for i in range(1500)` would be more efficient than your while statement.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in R directly, but perhaps you can just use the python code using the [rpython](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html) or [rpithon](http://rpithon.r-forge.r-project.org/) libraries

Comment: You may have to write your own UDP code in C or C++ and link it with R...

Comment: If I use R server, you think can I solve this problem? Can I make  a system to receive data via TCP in R

Comment: @user3698581 Did you find a solution for R to read the UDP protocol? I'm interested in the same topic, but can't find something concerning R and UDP ...

Comment: R itself don does not have socket capability, existing package mimic socket using Tcl extension, but unfortunately, Tcl doesn't have built-in UDP socket support.

Comment: @georgexsh- Agreed.

Comment: @J_F Unfortunately, I concur with `georgexsh` in that (As far as I can ascertain) there is no support for UDP in the R base platform or the R packages I have looked at. I searched the CRAN repo. That said -
 Zeromq distributed messaging platform does support UDP but the R interface `rzmq` does not yet appear to expose the functionality. My sense is that either `rzmq` or `base::connections` is the place to fix this. The easiest approach in my view is to could make a request of the `base::connections` to upgrade the socketConnection functionality.

Comment: @Technophobe01 Thanks again for your research! I also had the idea to make it directly in the `base`package and for that purpose I already cloned R-core from github to have the code.

Comment: @J_F If you publish via github happy to review with you. My sense is we need to update to allow the datagram type to be set. Sorry, that I couldn't find a more productive answer. :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JF,

My sense would be to write your code directly in C / C++ and include in your R program via the

- [R Rcpp package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html).

Using the above approach you can create a package that mimics the python functionality or just wrap the python code inside an RCPP package directly. This last point is covered in the following tutorial

- [Call Python from R through RCPP](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-python/)

I hope the above explanation and code example below will help point you in the right direction.

### Rcpp code example:

### Listener.R

```
setwd("~/dev/stackoverflow/40896072")

# install.packages("installr")
# require(installr)
# install.Rtools()
# install.packages("Rcpp")
# # Test and Verify
# Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")

Rcpp::sourceCpp( file = "./listener.cc")

listen()
```

### Listener.cc

```
/* listener.c - a datagram socket 'server'
 * simply displays message received then dies!
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#define MYPORT 5555 /* the port users connect to */
#define MAXBUFLEN 100

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int listen() {

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr; /* info for my addr i.e. server */
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; /* client's address info */
    socklen_t addr_len;
    ssize_t numbytes;
    char buf[ MAXBUFLEN];

    printf( "Running\n");

    if( (sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror( "Listener socket");
        exit( 1);
    }

    memset( &my_addr, 0, sizeof( my_addr)); /* zero struct */
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* host byte order ... */
    my_addr.sin_port = htons( MYPORT); /* ... short, network byte order */
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* any of server IP addrs */
    if( bind( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr,
             sizeof( struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror( "Listener bind");
        exit( 1);
    }
    addr_len = sizeof( struct sockaddr);

    if( (numbytes = recvfrom( sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN - 1, 0,
                             (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
        perror( "Listener recvfrom");
        exit( 1);
    }

    printf( "Got packet from %s\n", inet_ntoa( their_addr.sin_addr));
    printf( "Packet is %zd bytes long\n", numbytes);
    buf[ numbytes] = '\0'; /* end of string */
    printf( "Packet contains \"%s\"\n", buf);
    close( sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

### Client.R

```
setwd("~/dev/stackoverflow/40896072")

# install.packages("installr")
# require(installr)
# install.Rtools()
# install.packages("Rcpp")
# # Test and Verify
# Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")

Rcpp::sourceCpp( file = "./client.cc")

client()
```

### Client.cc

```
/* client.c - a datagram 'client'
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h> /* for gethostbyname() */

//#include <Rcpp.h>
//using namespace Rcpp;

#define PORT 5555 /* server port the client connects to */

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int client()
{
    socklen_t sockfd;
    ssize_t numbytes;
    struct hostent *he;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; /* server address info */
    /* resolve server host name or IP address */
    if ( (he = gethostbyname("localhost")) == NULL )
      {
        perror( "Talker gethostbyname");
        exit( 1);
      }

    if ( (sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
      {
        perror( "Talker socket");
        exit( 1);
      }

    memset( &their_addr,0, sizeof(their_addr) ); /* zero struct */
    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* host byte order .. */
    their_addr.sin_port = htons( PORT); /* .. short, netwk byte order */
    their_addr.sin_addr = *( (struct in_addr *)he -> h_addr);

    if( (numbytes = sendto( sockfd, "Hello", strlen("Hello"), 0,
                            (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr,
                            sizeof( struct sockaddr))) == -1)
    {
      perror( "Talker sendto");
      exit( 1);
    }

    printf( "Sent %zd bytes to %s\n", numbytes,
            inet_ntoa( their_addr.sin_addr));

    close( sockfd );
    return 0;
}
```

### Runtime output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! Of course I know that I can code it on my own. I tried it with Rcpp and the `BH` library. Nevertheless, I wonder why the UDP protocol is not part of the main library of R and TCP is ... so with R standard tools it is not possible? This was the main question why opening the question again and give a bounty.

Comment: @J_FI do not know the "Why", of it, but it is pretty clear it is missing. My sense **[Male Answer Syndrome]** - **[Off]** is that I do not know why it has been omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Is RMarkdown helpful for you to write your python code in and run it?

````
---
title: "socket_prog"
output: html_document
---


```{python}
import socket, traceback   
host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

counter = 1500
while counter > 0:
counter -= 1
try:
message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
message = message.decode() 
data = message.split(",")
print(data)


except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
raise
except:
traceback.print_exc()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

If R make.socket won't play nice w/UDP just use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to either relay UDP as TCP or pipe incoming data R.